# Distribution function with exponential-distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Given the r.v. $X$ with distribution function $F(x) = (1-e^{-x})_+$ (i.e. $X\sim\operatorname{Exp}(1)$), what is the distribution of $e^{-X}$?

Comment: Questions with zero context. Answers instantly accepted with no comment. Optimal in every respect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\Pr( e^{-X}\le 0) & = 0 \\[10pt]
\Pr(e^{-X} < 1) & = 1 \\[10pt]
\Pr( e^{-X} \le x) & = \Pr(-X \le \log x) = \Pr(X\ge -\log x) \\[10pt]
& = e^{-(-\log x)} = e^{\log x} = x.
\end{align}
$$
\text{So } F_{e^{-X}} (x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } x\le0, \\ x & \text{if } 0<x<1, \\ 1 & \text{if } x\ge 1. \end{cases}
$$
There is a standard name for that distribution.